# Match height of all tablerow

Tags: android, xml, tablelayout

As shown in the image I'm trying to fill the leftside shorttext to match the rightside long text. The long text on the rihtsite will dynamically change so it won't be static.

[image: TableExample]

Here is my code :

```
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:text="short text"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:stretchColumns="1"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/xml_cell_shape"/>
                <TextView android:text="long text is long really really long this is not a lie"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/xml_cell_shape"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:text="short text"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/xml_cell_shape"/>
                <TextView android:text="medium text not long nor short"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/xml_cell_shape"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap your TextViews inside TableRow in a LinearLayout. Like this

```
<TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/xml_cell_shape"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="short text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="@drawable/xml_cell_shape"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="long text is long really really long this is not a lie"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
```